# Failed to communicate with Ignite cluster while trying to execute multiple queries simultaneously using DBeaver

Tags: ignite, dbeaver

I am using Apache Ignite 2.3.0. I have configured ignite with DBeaver using apache ignite database driver.
It is working fine to execute the single query at a time. But when I am trying to execute two different queries on two SQL editor simultaneously,
i.e while execution of the first query on SQL editor, I am trying to execute another query on another SQL editor in DBeaver.
It throws **SQL Error [08006]: Failed to communicate with Ignite cluster**. As a result, both the queries get stopped the execution.

Comment: What queries do you execute and what do Ignite logs say?

Comment: Also, do you use the same JDBC connection, or separate for each query?

Comment: @Denis I am executing normal select queries. I am using DBeaver SQL editor with the same JDBC connection.

Answer (score 3):

Ignite JDBC driver is not thread-safe, so single connection cannot be used concurrently.

If you want to execute multiple SQL queries at the same time, you should create a separate connection for each thread.

Comment: I am able to execute multiple queries by creating separate connections. Thanks for your quick response.